# How do I compare multiple arrays and identify the closest match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, comparison

I have one array which contains the master data, e.g.:

```
[1, 3, 7, 11]
```

and a database with a table which contains arrays with various numbers, e.g:

```
1) [1, 5, 7, 11]
2) [2, 3, 4, 8, 10]
3) [1, 3, 7, 11, 15]
...
```

I am looking for an easy way to calculate which ones of the arrays are the closest one to the master data and rank it accordingly. The result would be that

1. No 3 - 100% match
2. No 1 - 75%
3. No 2 - 25%

This probably isn't very difficult, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it. Is there a function in ruby or a gem in rails that can help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `[11, 3, 7, 1, 15]` à 100% match?

Comment: Could you describe your algorithm? What makes No 1 a 75 % match, No 2 a 25% match and No 3 a 100% match?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right, it's actually not a 100% match - it contains 100% of the numbers from the master array but it is only an 80% match. it would be great if I could highlight both. Not sure how difficult this is...

Comment: @Stefan I'll try :) The master array contains 4 values, as a result each value that has a match represents a 25% increase. If the master array would have 5 values, each value would represent 20%

Comment: You need to edit to define precisely how the measure of similarity is defined. Do not try to explain in comments.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is take the master array and take each of the array. Make a intersection between the master and each array. Take the size of result which would give you the number of matched elements. Then if you need to find the percentage you can easily do that. A example:

```
 master = [1, 3, 7, 11]
 arrays = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,11,0], [1,2,3,7,11]]
 arrays.each{|a| puts ((master & a).size.to_f/master.size.to_f) * 100 }
```

This will give the percentage of match. Instead of arrays you need to use the data in your database. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

The above would only work when the array have unique element. If array has same elements and the order is not important then `uniq` can be used on both sides. But this would be partially correct as you can read the comments below. As @Cary Swoveland mentioned what might be wrong.

Comment: Suppose master and array were both `[1,1]`?

Comment: Thanks for denoting the mistake. I have corrected my answer but not sure if it will succeed in all scenarios or not. Please correct me if the answer is still wrong.

Comment: `uniq` won't work.Suppose the master were `[1,1]` and the array `[1]`. I presume that would be a 50% match, but we can't be sure because the question is not clear.

Comment: I have updated the answer more that it would be just a partial solution. Thanks for denoting the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming order is not important:

```
m = [1, 3, 7, 11]
a = [2, 3, 4, 8, 10].dup

m.reduce(0) do |t,i| 
  idx = a.index(i)
  if idx
    a.delete_at(idx)
    t+1
  else
    t
  end
end * 100 / a.size
  #=> 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `db_arrays` be the stored arrays and `array` the one you want to find the best match for.  I would do

```
ordered = db_arrays.sort_by{|db_array| (db_array & array).size}.reverse
```

this will give you db_arrays in order of how well they match (according to your criteria), best first.

EDIT: if you have a very large number of db_arrays then it might be better to try to do this with an sql query rather than loading them all out and testing them with ruby.

Comment: There is a problem when `array` has duplicates, as that information is lost when `&` is applied.

Comment: Hmm, that's true.  I wonder whether, according the questioner's requirements, `[1,2,3]` is deemed closer to `[1,1,2]` or `[1,2]`